# Query grouped data in django

Tags: django, models

I'm trying to optimize my very simple pagination system. I'm fetching a specific content from my models with

```
myModel.objects.get(slug='my slug bla bla bla')
```

and I'd like to be able to get in same request, the next and preceding Pk from my id, in order to display a next/prec button based on the Pk or posted. I've taken a look at pagination, but didn't found how to solve my prec = slug-pk - 1, slug, next = slug-pk + 1 with it.
At the moment i've added to fields in my model in order to fetch the next and prec absolute urls, but It's quite ugly and makes a lot of useless SQL queries. You can take a look at the output here: http://diasporamas.com/le-barbier-de-paris/watch

Any ideas on how to improve my fetching?

Thank you!

Comment: ok, I will ask a stupid question :) if you get an object from the DB, how you will get next and previous ones? (keep in mind, that there can be holes in the PK numbering, due to e.g. db rolbacks etc.)

If you would like to use pagination (and next/prev) buttons, you will need a set of objects, then Paginate it where number of objects per page will be equal to one. But! then you will be jumbing between pages, not objects themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that it's possible to do that in one query.

The most efficient way I can think of would be:

```
current = myModel.objects.get(slug='my slug bla bla bla')
next = None
next_pk = current.pk + 1
previous = None
prev_pk = current.pk - 1
for mod in myModel.objects.filter(pk__in=(next_pk, prev_pk)):
    if mod.pk == next_pk:
        next = mod
    else:
        prev = mod
```

Comment: Well that's actually the way I'm using to do it. But I thought there might be an advanced filterig feature that would permit to get obects on multiple filters...

Comment: You can do complex queries with [Q objects](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects) but that wouldn't help here- you still need to do the first query to get the id of the current post before you can query the others.